# is there a way to see mapreduce/hadoop configuration properties in command line.?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way we can see hadoop configuration properties such as mapreduce.framework.name, io.sort.mb, mapred.compress.map.output etc.. from command line.?, similar to set in hive..

Comment: You want to see or set Hadoop configuration properties?

Comment: I want to see the properties...

Comment: Do you want to see the properties of client? The client configuration may be different from the server configuration(such as NameNode, DataNode).

Comment: I agree that.. if there is a solution to see either one, i will be fine.. I prefer DataNode.. I just wanted to know whether there is any to see property.. If  yes, how.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, found a way to see the properties. Searched all Apache classes and Apache provided classes to give you configuration properties. There are few ways to get it.

1) hadoop org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf  -- This gives properties of all mapreduce jobs. It takes properties from mapred-site and mapred-defaults. It works any where and gives all the properties.

2) hadoop org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf  -- By running this, with option -confKey we can see the properties of any specific property..  eg: hadoop org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf -confKey io.sort.mb

3) hadoop org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration -- By running this we can see the properties from core-site and core-defaults..

to set the configuration properties we have the GenericConfiguration or ToolRunner is there any way.. Hope this is help ful..